# Implement modified architecture of LSTM cell in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I wish to modify the internal cell structure and equations of the standard LSTM cell representation(for example in the implementation of Keras). How do I do the same(which functions/modules to overwrite and in which file of the Keras implementation)?
Any other suggestions in terms of libraries or frameworks are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new class of the LSTM cell, you can find the source code on the keras github repo. After that you need to create a new class that serves as your new layer and call your cell from the **init** layer in this custom layer. It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but I can recommend reading:

[This this tutorial](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and [this code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py).

Comment: I want to do some experiments in the internal structure of the LSTM cell like tweaking the internal connections and making some internal modifications in the flow of information within the cell. Would be grateful for any suggestions in that direction @ErikBrorson